# Does image file varies on different subscriptions in azure

Tags: powershell, azure, image-file

I have to use the same image file for creating vm in azure using different subscriptions. Whether the image files varies for different subscriptions? How to check that image file varies for each subscription using power shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

The Image files don't wary between different subscriptions, however the pricing may vary.
you can get the exact image name using the command Get-AzureVMImage , a Sample can be seen here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495275.aspx

```
C:\PS> $subsId = <MySubscriptionID>C:\PS> $cert = Get-AzureCertificate cert:\LocalMachine\MY\<CertificateThumbprint>
C:\PS> $MyOSImages = Get-AzureVMImage
```

There can be multiple versions of the same image as it releases over the period of time, you'll be using the latest one.